# Force download a file in PHP

Tags: php, html

Hello everyone I am developing a PHP MVC framework and I reached a point where  I need to offer the user some files and I don't know how ro create the download link I know it sounds childish but I tried to make hyperlink to the address of the document but it seems not to work....Some documentation would be ideal

Answer (score 4):

```
$fullpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/foldername/document.pdf"; //Full path of document
$filename = "document.pdf";  //Document file nmae


  $mm_type="application/octet-stream";

    header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: hack");
    header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
    header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fullpath)) );
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
```